# How can I click on the li Item using Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

How can I select list items that are nested like this:

```
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
<div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-36" role="option"><span class="select2-`match"></span>
Risk
</div>
</li>
```

Because each list items differs only from the Text it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Risk** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable']/div[@class='select2-result-label' and contains(., 'Risk')]")).click();
  ```

However, as the element is a dynamic element so to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@class='select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable']/div[@class='select2-result-label' and contains(., 'Risk')]"))).click();
  ```